# Gradle cannot resolve package for java 11 module when in one of two directories

Tags: gradle, groovy, java-11, java-module

I am trying to compile a java 11 module which contains mixed java and groovy code, and the compilation keeps failing with the following message:

> package is empty or does not exist: my.sample.map

I changed the `GroovyCompile` task to use the java 11 compilation flags:

```
tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs += [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '-verbose',
                '--module-source-path', ["$rootProject.projectDir/*/src/main/{java,groovy}/",
                                         "$rootProject.projectDir/*/src/main/"].join(File.pathSeparator)
        ]
    }
}
```

I have the following folder structure for the module that I am trying to compile:

```
my.sample.module
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── groovy
    │   │   └── my
    │   │       └── sample
    │   │           └── map
    │   │               ├── MapComponent.groovy
    │   │               └── MapViewPerspective.groovy
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── my
    │   │       └── sample
    │   │           └── map
    │   │               └── config
    │   │                   └── MapViewConfig.java
    │   ├── module-info.java
    │   └── resources
    │       └── MapView.fxml
    └── test
```

The contents of `module-info.java` is as follows:

```
module my.sample.module {
    exports my.sample.map.config;
    exports my.sample.map;

    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;

    requires org.codehaus.groovy;

    ...
}
```

After hours of trying to fix this, the only problem I can see is that it is skipping the `groovy` folder and only looking for stuff in the `java` folder.

Then I tried to add an empty class to the package `my.sample.map` in the `java` folder, and the compilation proceeds past that point but fails when compiling classes in the `groovy` folder which need `MapViewConfig` from the `java` folder.

What am I doing wrong? I think I have to update the classpaths used for compilation, but I'm not sure which classpaths to add.

Comment: It seems that the main problem is that groovy does not support modularized applications yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Groovy [release notes](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#Groovy3.0releasenotes-Splitpackages), Groovy 3 does not yet have support for Java module system, but the changes are slowly making their way in.

> Groovy 3 is making changes to allow the codebase to move towards the
>   compliant rules and allow Groovy users to begin the migration process.
>   Groovy 4 is our target version for fully-compliant artifacts but you
>   can start getting your classes ready ahead of time while using Groovy
>   3.

Looks like Groovy 4 is the golden release we have to wait for. At least they are working on it, so we just have to wait patiently.